# signals in VHDL for .. generate scope

Tags: scope, vhdl

A linting tool doesn't like the following block of code, because it thinks that the signals declared inside the for..generate scope have multiple drivers. Intuitively, I would expect that for each signal declaration, one instance of the signal would exist for each iteration of the loop.

Is the linter broken, or is it the VHDL language that is broken?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity demo is
end demo;

architecture rtl of demo is
  type i_arr_t is array(integer range <>) of integer;
  signal results: i_arr_t(0 to 1);
  signal dot : integer;
begin
  g_gen : for ii in 0 to 1 generate
    signal sig : integer;
  begin
    sig <= ii * 2;
    results(ii) <= sig;
  end generate;

  dot <= results(0) + results(1);
end rtl;
```

Error message: `Non-resolved signal 'sig' has multiple drivers`

Comment: I think your linting tool is wrong.

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.5 Elaboration of a statement part, 14.5.3 Generate statements. "Elaboration of a generate statement consists of the replacement of the generate statement with zero or more copies of a block statement whose declarative part consists of declarative items contained within the generate statement and whose statement part consists of concurrent statements contained within the generate statement. ...", also see 12.2 Scope of declarations para 4, the scope of each `sig` declaration only extends to a configuration declaration for each block statement.

Comment: Just put this in simulation, take a screenshot showing the different instantiations of the signal and show it to whoever takes care of the linting tool.